# Minimal Requirements fot bcp.exe

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Hi Guys i want to use bcp.exe in a programm but i dont know what files I have to copy. I tried  bcp.exe and bcp.rll it didn't work. Does someone know what files are missing?

Comment: At first glance from Dependency Walker, SQLNCL11.dll (at least in SQL 2012). But there may be more, and COM components, etc. You are also likely not allowed to just redistribute bcp.exe. Can't you final an alternative interface to use? There used to be SQLXML components I think?

Comment: What kind of program, .NET?

Comment: Thanks for the answers I want to try this programm with bcp and i am using it in the moment but with a full sql server management studio instal. The Programm is written in Java and accesses a Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the command line utilities.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36433

For a specific version look up the SQL feature pack that correlates to the version of SQL you wish to use. Example;
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295